# Bootstrap dropdown and Jquery click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an action when someone click on a element of my dropdown.

I don't understand why, click function doesn't work.

My html code :

```
<div class="row">
                <div class="dropdown col-lg-12">
                    <button class="btn btn-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown"
                            aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                        Veuillez sélectionner la manière dont vous souhaitez nous contacter
                        <span class="caret"></span>
                    </button>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu1">
                        <li><a href="#" id="callback">Etre rappelé</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" id="sendMail">Envoyer un message</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

My Jquery code :

```
var phoneForm = $("#phoneForm");
console.log($("#callback"));
console.log($("#phoneForm").hasClass("hidden"));
$("#callback").click(function(){
    console.log("entre dans la fonction click");
    if(phoneForm.hasClass("hidden")){
        console.log("entre dans le if");
        phoneForm.removeClass("hidden");
    }
});
```

Never it goes in click function.

Thanks

Comment: Are you putting this code inside `$(function(){ /* code here*/ })` or `$(document).ready(function(){ /* code here*/ })` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your javascript code is getting executed before those elements exist,

I suggest you to try like this

```
  $(function(){ // Wait until you have all html printed
       var phoneForm = $("#phoneForm");
       console.log($("#callback"));
       console.log($("#phoneForm").hasClass("hidden"));
       $("#callback").click(function(){
          console.log("entre dans la fonction click");
          if(phoneForm.hasClass("hidden")){
             console.log("entre dans le if");
             phoneForm.removeClass("hidden");
          }
       });
   });
```

Comment: Thank you. It was the problem, I didn't wait the end of load.
I had this function : jQuery(window).load(afterLoad);

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery version above 1.9.1
with following code
`$(function(){ // Wait until you have all html printed
       var phoneForm = $("#phoneForm");
       console.log($("#callback"));
       console.log($("#phoneForm").hasClass("hidden"));
       $("#callback").click(function(){
          console.log("entre dans la fonction click");
          if(phoneForm.hasClass("hidden")){
             console.log("entre dans le if");
             phoneForm.removeClass("hidden");
          }
       });
   });`